# How to skip login and remote authorisation pages when authenticating using oauth webserver flow?

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce

I want to access a rest webservice hosted in a salesforce org from another Salesforce org. I am using the web server flow for authentication. When hitting the authorisation URL, I am redirected to a login page and after login, remote authorisation page appears requiring the user to allow/deny access. I somehow want to skip this login and approval when I access the web service next time. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If the authentication server (server that issues tokens) is following OAuth1.0 strictly, skipping the user login dialog is not possible with OAuth1.0.

It is possible with OAuth2.0 with the Client Credentials Grant pattern, but that pattern is used for highly trusted clients and I am pretty sure that Salesforce does not support that.